# How to quickly uncompress the assets into cache?

Tags: android, lua

I made a android application that used many lua script,everytime i run the application,it will spend to many time to read those script in the apk,how too quickly uncompress those into cache(data/data/xxx) ?
Those script in so many differrent folder,I don't want to 'mkdir'...it's horrible.
May i should make a file struct like MPQ?

Comment: Your question is rambling and doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you want to decompress the files from the apk into cache, your options are to write them all out at the beginning, or to do it as needed.  The first way has a high cost on first load, the second has a cost every time you load a new script.  As for "mkdir" being horrible-  that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: all right...I'm so foolish...I always used c++ to make android application,the led me forgot 'java'...